# Simple way to setup PHP/MySQL in OS X?

Tags: php

Web-development novice here. I want to try implementing a simple web site that uses PHP and MySQL but I don't want to pay for server/domain hosting. Is there a simple way to just try out my implementation using only the local resources on my MacBook Pro (OS X 10.7) before making it live online? If so, what do I have to install? Thanks!

Comment: This is all you need (an Apache Server with PHP an MySQL to be used out of the box): http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html - just follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache as webserver and install PHP, if i'm right apache is already installed in you OS, you can google for an apache+php instal tutorial for mac.
and if you dont want to mess with anything, use xamp

Answer (score 1):

Check MAMP

http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can download source codes and compile everything as you want, but I strongly recommend [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html). It contains probably all you need out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Just download Xampp, it contains anything you need.

http://www.apachefriends.org/de/xampp.html